# How can an input field open a new window after pressing enter in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an input field that I need to open a new window after the value is entered and I hit enter. The way I have it right now is after the value is entered it goes to this url `https://search.broward.org/texis/search/?pr=FLLComplete&query=' + e.target.value` in the same window.

```
<div class="input-group">
     <i class="catalog-search-icon fa-regular fa-magnifying-glass active"></i>
          <input type="search" placeholder="Search Airport" aria-label="Search" name="searchterms" title="Search" alt="Search" id="airportSearchInput" size="20">
</div>

    $(document).ready(function() {
        
            $('#airportSearchInput').on("keyup", function(e){
        
                if(e.code === "Enter" || e.key === "Enter") {
                  window.location.href = 'https://search.broward.org/texis/search/?pr=FLLComplete&query=' + e.target.value;
            
            }
        });
    
        });
```

Comment: How to open a new window using JavaScript, is something you should very much be able to research on your own. (Make an effort, instead of coming here expecting us to do ALL the work for you! [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1427878)) You might however run into problems with the popup blockers that most modern browsers come with by default, if they can't see a direct connection between a user interaction, and the attempt to open the popup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `window.open(url)` to open your url in a new new tab

Comment: Thanks Tharindu for your help!